# how to connect several devices by itself ios

Tags: ios, swift

I need your help, I dont know how to connect a lot of devices and sync, for example turn on the light at the same time in all devices but i dont want to connect to a LAN or something like that,I have tried by WiFi but it is async, I have used gps date and for sync this  example if the hour end on pair value, I turn on the light but its not efficient.

```
// get location

  var manager: CLLocationManager

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedAlways || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last!

    if !timerStarted {
        self.startTimeInterval =     location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow
        self.time = location.timestamp
        timerStarted = true
        self.syncSecond()

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

and i use connection wifi or bluetooth

```
MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate
MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate
MCSessionState 
MCSessionDelegate
```

only, i'm doing tests

Comment: Do you have any examples of any other apps/devices doing this?

Comment: i don't have an example, i need to connect a lot of devices without internet, but i need sync all devices, for example. change color of the background at the same time.